# MVC 5, App_Data empty, despite show all files.

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio-2013

I have built a new MVC project, and copy and pasted some sample data into the Configuration.cs file.

And I have also updated the Web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ParkingDbContext"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; 
    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mockParkShare-db.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

(There was no detfaultconnection string. )

And I ran update-database, and I can not find the .mdf file under App_data. Infact, I can not find it anywhere. 
I have tried show hidden files.

Anybody has a clue where my database went?

Comment: Are you sure your context is using `ParkingDbContext` instead of `DetfaultConnection`?

Answer (score 1):

Try C:\Users\username.

The easiest way to find the DB will be connecting to `(LocalDb)\v11.0` using SQL Server management studio, then right-clicking the DB and selecting properties. Under the files option you should be able to see where the actual Db file is located.

[image]

Edit: Here's an article explaining: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/05/10231206.aspx

Comment: I have installed sql server management studio, but: 
IN the mean while, I did try `add-migrations -enablemigrations -force` . 
Then I'm faced with 'sql server service failed to start' error. 
Now I can not connect to local anymore, through sql server management studio. 
and `sqllocaldb.exe delete v11.0` doesn't work either. 
So sorry! don't know what to do!